# Uncaught Error:React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop ( ReactAnimatedWeather )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made weather app using weather API , and I got infinite loop error when I had icons code inside ( `switch` `case` loop). I want the `icon` to be updated by the current weather state from API!
Can somebody help me on this? how to solve the infinite loop error..?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactAnimatedWeather from 'react-animated-weather';

function Weather() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({
    city: undefined,
    temp_current: undefined,
    temp_max: undefined,
    temp_min: undefined,
    current: undefined,
    icon: undefined,
  });

  const convertCelsius = (temp) => {
    let cel = Math.floor(temp - 273.15);
    return cel;
  };

  const defaults = {
    color: 'white',
    size: 100,
    animate: true,
  };

  const getWeather = async (lat, lon) => {
    const API_KEY = '9916e4e6fd6079aa9a9fec8e0c218fc5';
    const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${API_KEY}&lang=kr`;
    const response = await fetch(API_URL);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

    setWeather({
      city: data.name,
      temp_current: convertCelsius(data.main.temp),
      temp_max: convertCelsius(data.main.temp_max),
      temp_min: convertCelsius(data.main.temp_min),
      current: data.weather[0].main,
    });
  };

  // icon
  switch (weather.current) {
    case 'Haze':
      setWeather({ ...weather, icon: 'CLEAR_DAY' });
      break;
    case 'Clouds':
      setWeather({ ...weather, icon: 'CLOUDY' });
      break;
    case 'Snow':
      setWeather({ ...weather, icon: 'SNOW' });
      break;
    case 'Drizzle':
      setWeather({ ...weather, icon: 'SLEET' });
      break;
    case 'Dust':
    case 'Tornado':
      setWeather({ ...weather, icon: 'WIND' });
      break;
    case 'Fog':
    case 'Smoke':
      setWeather({ ...weather, icon: 'FOG' });
      break;
    case 'Rain':
    case 'Mist':
      setWeather({ ...weather, icon: 'RAIN' });
      break;
    default:
      setWeather({ ...weather, icon: 'CLEAR_DAY' });
      break;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // get geolocation
    let lat, lon;
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      console.log('geolocation available');
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async (position) => {
        try {
          lat = position.coords.latitude;
          lon = position.coords.longitude;
          getWeather(lat, lon);
        } catch (error) {
          getWeather(37.53, 127.02);
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert('geoloaction not available');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="weather">
      <div className="weather-info">
        <h1 className="location">{weather.city}</h1>
        <div className="temperature">
          <p className="current">{weather.temp_current}&deg;</p>
          <ul className="minmax">
            <li>{weather.temp_min}&deg;</li>
            <li>{weather.temp_max}&deg;</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="weather-icon">
        <ReactAnimatedWeather
          icon={weather.icon ? weather.icon : 'CLEAR_DAY'}
          color={defaults.color}
          size={defaults.size}
          animate={defaults.animate}
        />
        <p className="state">{weather.current}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Weather;
```

Comment: Try to wrap the switch statement in a `useEffect`. I think infinite loop is due to that

Comment: Your switch block is changing state directly in the main function. This causes a re-render, which causes a function call, which causes a re-render, etc, etc. Move the switch block inside the async function where you compose your weather state based on the API result (not as-is, obviously).

Comment: The `switch` statement is calling `setWeather` unconditionally. When you want this logic to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what @Oliver BN  said or try this

```
  setWeather({
          city: data.name,
          temp_current: convertCelsius(data.main.temp),
          temp_max: convertCelsius(data.main.temp_max),
          temp_min: convertCelsius(data.main.temp_min),
          current: data.weather[0].main,
          icon: buildIcon(data.weather[0].main),
        });
      };

      function buildIcon(current) {
        switch (current) {
          case "Haze":
            return "CLEAR_DAY";
            break;
          case "Clouds":
            return "CLOUDY";
            break;
          // ...
          default:
            return "CLEAR_DAY";
            break;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your switch block is calling setState, which re-renders the component and calls the switch block again:

```
switch (weather.current) {
    case 'Haze':
      setWeather({ ...weather, icon: 'CLEAR_DAY' });
      break;
```

Move this switch block into the useEffect function to run it once on load, or better yet load the icon as part of the async API call function to check on every call to the API:

```
const getWeather = async (lat, lon) => {
    const API_KEY = '9916e4e6fd6079aa9a9fec8e0c218fc5';
    const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${API_KEY}&lang=kr`;
    const response = await fetch(API_URL);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);



 //Set Icon here
const weatherIcon = 

    setWeather({
      city: data.name,
      temp_current: convertCelsius(data.main.temp),
      temp_max: convertCelsius(data.main.temp_max),
      temp_min: convertCelsius(data.main.temp_min),
      current: data.weather[0].main,
icon: weatherIcon 
    });
  };
```